# Mindtap Column Styles

Tags: html, css

I am running into a problem I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it. I am inputting the code under the column styles using a div element and I feel I am following the directions correctly which is:

> Column Styles
> Next, you’ll format the grid columns.
> Go to the Column Styles section.
> Create a style rule to float all div elements whose class value starts with “col-” on the left margin.
> Set the padding around all such elements to 2%.
> Finally, apply the Border Box Sizing model to the content of those elements. (Note: Remember to use web extensions to provide support for older browsers.)
> In the same section, create style rules for div elements with class names .col-1-1, .col-1-2, .col-1-3, .col-2-3, .col-1-4, and .col-3-4 to set their widths to 100%, 50%, 33.33%, 66.67%, 25%, and 75% respectively.

But for some reason I keep getting this error when executing the code:

> Simulation Output
> 364.8125px Traceback (most recent call last):   File "nt-test-7a61bdd2.py", line 10, in 
> assert('133.' in elm.value_of_css_property('width')) AssertionError Test Contents from selenium import webdriver from
> selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys driver =
> webdriver.PhantomJS() driver.get('{{localhost}}/pc_specials.html')
> driver.implicitly_wait(1) elm =
> driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.col-1-3')
> print(elm.value_of_css_property('width')) assert('133.' in
> elm.value_of_css_property('width')) driver.close()"

I don't know why I keep getting this error and I would appreciate if anyone can help me understand what is going on because this has been driving me crazy. I am doing this on Mindtap btw.

My code is listed as a Png link, can you please take a look:

[image]